# This C++ variadic template has undefined behavior, right?

Tags: c++, g++, variadic-templates, undefined-behavior, default-arguments

I'm investigating corner cases in templates and found this interesting situation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<class... T>
void bar(int i=42, T&&... ts)
{
    printf("%d ", i);
    printf("%d\n", ts..., -1);
}

int main()
{
    bar();    // 42 -1 (on Clang and GCC)
    bar(1);   // 1 -1 (on Clang and GCC)
    bar(1,2); // 1 2 (on GCC; hard error on Clang)
}
```

<sub>(Since this came up in the comments: Notice that I have carefully crafted the `printf` calls so that *they* don't invoke undefined behavior. Passing extra unused arguments to a plain old variadic function (such as `printf`) is always okay.)</sub>

[On Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/izrMvBH9CViN4wMD), Clang 4.0.0 does not diagnose the template definition of `bar`, despite diagnosing many other (8.2) violations — and happily compiles `bar(1)` — but Clang does generate a hard error from the actual call to `bar(1,2)`.

[On Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/izrMvBH9CViN4wMD), GCC 7.0.0 happily compiles both `bar(1)` and `bar(1,2)`, which is... interesting. ;)

My take on it is that this code (even without the `main`) runs afoul of N4606 14.6/(8.2): the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if "every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack".

Which means that Clang and GCC are within their rights to compile it (because it's undefined behavior); but I'm surprised both that Clang lets the `bar` definition pass (because Clang is normally so strict about (8.2) violations) and also that GCC lets `bar(1,2)` pass (because how does that even happen? c'mon, GCC).

Am I correct that this translation unit exhibits undefined behavior, even if `bar` is never instantiated at all?

Comment: 14.6 doesn't apply because the call does generate a valid specialization, but the error happens at runtime inside the call to `printf`.

Comment: Sorry, what is 8.2?

Comment: @0x499602D2: I'm not even sure it's UB to provide additonal arguments that aren't used. The only constraint that I could find is that arguments must have the right type for the corresponding conversion specifier, but I'm not sure that implies that there must be such a specifier.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's not a UB to have additional arguments that are not used, according to C99 7.19.6.1/2: "If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored."

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "hard error"

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494765/interaction-between-default-arguments-and-parameter-pack-gcc-and-clang-disagree.  **Notes from the April, 2013 meeting:** CWG agreed that the example should be ill-formed. **Notes from the September, 2013 meeting:** CWG agreed that this example should be accepted.   No updates since then...

Comment: @0x499602D2 why would there be in a error in printf?

Comment: @Brian whoops, sorry, my refactoring of the question pushed the definition of "8.2" past my first reference to it. "8.2" is supposed to refer to N4606 14.6/(8.2): namely, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if "every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack".

Comment: @M.M: by "hard error" I mean "error that can't be suppressed or ignored", i.e. pretty much I could have left out the word "hard", I was just emphasizing. :)  [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=hard+error) tells me: "an error ... causing failure ... especially one that gives no option of recovery."

Comment: "*Clang does generate a hard error*..." Can you post the error? It would save me the trouble of compiling your sample and trying to figure out if the error I'm getting is the same error that you're talking about.

Comment: @Cornstalks: I've hyperlinked to Wandbox now, so you can go check it out there. For the record, the actual error message is `error: missing default argument on parameter 'ts'`.